# How do I handle US State Income Tax for the 2020 COVID-19 Coronavirus Filing Extension

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

While the [IRS has a page on the Coronavirus impact](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus) is there any resource on handling the various State Income taxes. Are they extended like the Federal Income tax or do I have some relief due the declining economic conditions?

Edit: This is more of a placeholder question for my answer below, which provides a link to a US professional accounting association resource.

Comment: Admin: as this is a timely issue along with its link only nature, I'm okay with post modification or removal once the current situation has normalized.

Comment: The situation is very fluid. The US government changed the rules twice in a week. Give the states time to react. Nobody knows even if that will be the last change by the Federal government.

Comment: Each state is different. There is no general answer for all states; which state are you asking about?

Comment: @user102008 Updated question to reflect that this "question" is more of a reference to a professional organization's resource. And yes I know that normally each state is specific but it is a lot easier to look through one document if you happen to have income from multiple states.

Comment: There is no single answer.  Each state makes its own rules for income tax, so there are potentially 43 different answers.  (Since 7 states don't have an income tax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resource where individuals and small business owners can check is:

[The American Institute of Certified Professional Accountants document on Coronavirus State Filing Relief](https://www.aicpa.org/content/dam/aicpa/advocacy/tax/downloadabledocuments/coronavirus-state-filing-relief.pdf)

The document is broken down by state and has links to the various state income tax agencies. As the situation is changing, the document is being updated (although I don't know how frequently, but as of March 21, 2020 there appear to be March 20 updates).

**Given that the situation is fluid please check the above document has been updated for the states you are interested in. And be aware that further changes are possible for your states of interest.**

**Followup - the document is still being updated as of June 3 and now runs some 477 pages. You may wish to seek professional accountants for guidance.**

Additionally here is the link to [AICPA Coronavirus Resource Center](https://www.aicpa.org/news/aicpa-coronavirus-resource-center.html)